# Get the default `AccountController` in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

When creating a new .NET Core 2.1 web project with individual authentication, the project will be created with `AccountController` and `ManageController` alongside it.

The command is:

> dotnet new mvc --auth Individual

However, where can I find the default `AccountController` and `ManageController` in .NET Core 2.2 new project? I need to modify my default login logic.

Comment: They implemented it as Razor Pages compiled into an assembly. You can have it drop the files to override that with the right [scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity).

Comment: you can create them manually, or scaffoiding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore21

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default you cannot because from **ASP.NET Core 2.1** Identity is being provided as **Razor Class Library** with the ASP.NET Core project templates. If you want to see those Identity related codes and customize then you have to [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)  in your project.

Moreover if you need ASP.NET Core Identity in MVC format then here is my GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/TanvirArjel/AspNetCoreMvcIdentity)  where Razor Page Identity has been converted to MVC in **ASP.NET Core Version >= 2.2.**

Comment: Wow. That document is exactly what I need. Thank you!