# .NET Core Web application - where is the Microsoft Identity database?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm developing a .NET Core Web application with Microsoft Identity. Where is the database with the users? I need to modify and delete some of them. I need to look at the database and I don't know where it's stored or how to open it!

Edit: So the database is in the app.db file. But does anyone know how I can examine the same database once I've published the Web Application into Azure cloud? Somewhere in portal.azure.com, that is.

Anyone??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the default \`AccountController\` in .NET Core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154127/get-the-default-accountcontroller-in-net-core-2-2)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created a new project, selected authentication with invididual user accounts and "store user accounts in-app", and ran `update-database` from your `Package Manager Console` to create the database. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to access the database anyway.

If you take a look at the `appsettings.json` file, you can find the connection string for the database under `DefaultConnection`.

*Edit*: Okay, you are using SQLite. Therefore, you can use a SQLite browser, such as https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: in appsettings.json, it says this: "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "DataSource=app.db"
  } . But I don't know how to examine this app.db file.

Comment: Thank you - that works to open the app.db file great! But do you know how I can examine the same database that I publish into Azure cloud? Somewhere in portal.azure.com.